# Hold, Evaluate and similar (very general question)

Tags: evaluation, core-language

I read The Mathematica Book, Fifth Edition but I rally haven't been able to grasp how the Hold, HoldPattern, HoldComplete, HoldForm, Evaluate, Unevaluated and similary commands work: Do you know about a source that explains with simple examples, in some way accessible to normal (not outstandingly bright) people how they work and which are the cases when it's more advisabile to use theme and when it's necessary to use them? Thank you.

Comment: I imagine these older materials are probably still relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616592/mathematica-unevaluated-vs-defer-vs-hold-vs-holdform-vs-holdallcomplete-vs-etc and http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html